# How to set Windows Server DNS to resolve recursively for every IP in my subnet?

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, active-directory

Windows Server DNS server (active directory integrated) does not resolve for linux clients in my subnet, but resolves for Windows machines that are domain members.

Disable recursion checkbox is NOT checked.

Strange thing is even when a query does not require recursion (interogating with dig for a name in the domain it is authoritative on) it says the same thing:

```
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available
```

How do I get it to resolve for linux clients?